# What happens if I fart on someone's balls?

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

Do you ever get the chance to fart on someone's balls? So far Cartman and Randy have told me "*never fart on anyone's balls"* but I have yet to find someone I can do this to.

Ultimately, what happens if you do fart on someone's balls?

Comment: Boy, Stick of Truth is sure producing some great titles. :P

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This happens

> in the finale; you fart on Princess Kenny's balls and therefore revert the zombie apocalypse. Somehow. So I guess farting on someone's balls is a magic win button. It makes as much sense as the rest of the game

So yes, just wait and find out :)

Comment: I'd love to speculate on the genesis of the exhortation by contrasting to the ending of a specific film, but can't think how best to do that without adding a spoiler which I can't hide from a comment…!